# Sass/Compass Minified CSS and making quick changes

Tags: css, sass

Our team works with many websites that use Sass/Compass to compile and minify CSS.

Working with this current setup is great when you have all of the files stored locally and your development workflow is setup. However, when you push the site live and a few days down the road are asked to make a change, it's not a huge deal, the local files are there and you just have to compile and push up again.

But if you are working with a site someone else pushed live and now need to make a small change requested by the client, you have to pull all the files down, setup the development workflow with Sass/Compass and make the changes then compile and push up again.

This process is extremely time consuming when you have to make 20 small changes in a day.

It would be ideal to only have to:

- pull one file down,
- make the change,
- push it live and somehow the server complies it.

I haven't been able to find a solution and I also am not an experienced server side developer, so I'm asking you guys if you have a better development workflow setup that allows for all of this to happen and yet, makes it easy to make small changes in the future.

Comment: **"delete the local files"** Here's your problem. Why are you deleting the base files?

Comment: Get hold of the original SASS files?

Comment: I want to know if there's a way to pull down just one of the sass files, make a change and reupload

Comment: It's very unlikely that the Sass files will be on the production site...in fact there is no need for them to be there. You need to get hold of the original files...all of them.

Comment: If I were you, I would version sass folder (if not the whole app less config files) with Git. Every time you need to make a change, you just git pull everything, make your changes locally, git push to remote, and git pull again from the production server.

Answer (score 0):

Little information, but I think it would have to do to use partial file css several are not generated to compile.